# Create rows in dataframe for variable that was observed but not explicitly recorded by factor

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

I created a variable describing a species' group as domestic, wild or exotic based on a dataframe where each row represented the species found in unique sites (siteID). I want to insert rows into my dataframe by each siteID to report 0 for a group(s) that was not observed at that site. In other words this is the dataframe I have:

```
df.start <- data.frame(species = c("dog","deer","toucan","dog","deer","toucan"), 
    siteID = c("a","b","b","c","c","c"), 
    group = c("domestic", "wild", "exotic", "domestic", "wild", "exotic"), 
    value = c(2:7))

df.start
#   species siteID    group value
# 1     dog      a domestic     2
# 2    deer      b     wild     3
# 3  toucan      b   exotic     4
# 4     dog      c domestic     5
# 5    deer      c     wild     6
# 6  toucan      c   exotic     7
```

This is the data frame I want:

```
df.end <-data.frame(species=c("dog","NA","NA","NA","deer",
                              "toucan","dog","deer","toucan"),
    siteID = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"),
    group = rep(c("domestic", "wild", "exotic"),3), 
    value = c(2,0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7))

df.end
#   species siteID    group value
# 1     dog      a domestic     2
# 2      NA      a     wild     0
# 3      NA      a   exotic     0
# 4      NA      b domestic     0
# 5    deer      b     wild     3
# 6  toucan      b   exotic     4
# 7     dog      c domestic     5
# 8    deer      c     wild     6
# 9  toucan      c   exotic     7
```

This came up because I wanted to use a plyr function to summarize the mean values by group and I realized the zeros were missing for some groups site combinations and inflating my estimate. Maybe I'm missing a more obvious workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Using base R functions:

```
result <- merge(  
  with(df.start, expand.grid(siteID=unique(siteID),group=unique(group))),
  df.start,
  by=c("siteID","group"),
  all.x=TRUE
)
result$value[is.na(result$value)] <- 0

> result
  siteID    group species value
1      a domestic     dog     2
2      a   exotic    <NA>     0
3      a     wild    <NA>     0
4      b domestic    <NA>     0
5      b   exotic  toucan     4
6      b     wild    deer     3
7      c domestic     dog     5
8      c   exotic  toucan     7
9      c     wild    deer     6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 df.sg <- data.frame(xtabs(value~siteID+group, data=df.start))
 merge(df.start[-4], df.sg, by=c("siteID", "group"), all.y=TRUE)
#-------------
  siteID    group species Freq
1      a domestic     dog    2
2      a   exotic    <NA>    0
3      a     wild    <NA>    0
4      b domestic    <NA>    0
5      b   exotic  toucan    4
6      b     wild    deer    3
7      c domestic     dog    5
8      c   exotic  toucan    7
9      c     wild    deer    6
```

The `xtabs` function returns a table which lets the `as.data.frame.table` method works on it. Very handy.

Comment: Nice answer. I feel like there has to be an `aggregate` solution, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: I don't think so. `aggregate` discards (or perhaps never notices) the missing cross-combinations. `aggregate(df.start$value, df.start[, c("siteID", "group")], FUN=I)`